# get dictionary value using .(dot) operator using dynamic keyword, it's possible?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, arguments

I have the following class:

```
public class foo
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public foo(params object[] args)
        {
            foreach (object arg in args)
            {
                data.Add(arg.ToString(), "..");
            }
        }
    }
```

I need get the value of dictionary using the dot operadotor it's because the class that I set the class as arguments use the dynamic keyword to "walk" on the class.

for example:

```
 var args = new[] {"a","b","c"};
 var Foo = new foo(args);
 var baa = Foo.data.a;
 Console.Write(baa); // ..
```

if exists an way to make dynamic variables, something like:

```
public foo(params object[] args) {
foreach (object arg in args) {
  var name = (string) arg;
  var value = "..";
  MakeVariable(name, value);  
}
}
```

makes an variable named of `arg`  and the value `..` as `public` member of `foo` class.

anyway differents  to solve this is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have `Foo` inherit from `DynamicObject`:

```
public class Foo : DynamicObject
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Foo(params object[] args)
    {
        foreach (object arg in args)
        {
            data.Add(arg.ToString(), "..");
        }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (data.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = data[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }
}
```

To use it you can use `dynamic` to hold an instance of `Foo`:

```
var args= new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
dynamic foo = new Foo(args);
var myA = foo.a; //returns ".."
```

Keep in mind that you will lose type safety since you have to use `dynamic` - your use case should really justify this disadvantage - usually there is a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28VS.100%29.aspx).  If you are using an older version of the framework the only option is **[Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kyyyeh2.aspx)**

The dynamic works something like this

```
// If you try to get a value of a property 
// not defined in the class, this method is called.
public override bool TryGetMember(
    GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
{
    // Converting the property name to lowercase
    // so that property names become case-insensitive.
    string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

    // If the property name is found in a dictionary,
    // set the result parameter to the property value and return true.
    // Otherwise, return false.
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
}

// If you try to set a value of a property that is
// not defined in the class, this method is called.
public override bool TrySetMember(
    SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
{
    // Converting the property name to lowercase
    // so that property names become case-insensitive.
    dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

    // You can always add a value to a dictionary,
    // so this method always returns true.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [`ExpandoObject` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) if you want to directly expose the `Data` member, as in your example. This keeps the code simpler if you don't need to define specific operations that would require inheriting `DynamicObject`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public dynamic Data = new ExpandoObject();
    public Foo(params object[] args)
    {
        var dataDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)Data;
        foreach (var obj in args)
        {
            dataDict.Add(obj.ToString(), "..");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var foo = new Foo("a", "b", "c");
Console.WriteLine(foo.Data.a);    

((IDictionary<string, object>)foo.Data).Add("d", "!");

foreach (var item in foo.Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Notice that I cast to a dictionary and added "d" although I could've also assigned it directly: `foo.Data.d = "!"`. The only difference is you may not know ahead of time what field names you have, and the former example allows you to setup the `ExpandoObject` based on dynamic input, whereas the latter is useful when you already know what field name to use.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4  this exact behavior is implemented by [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly ExpandoObject _dict = new ExpandoObject();

    public dynamic Data
    {
        get { return _dict; }
    }

    public Foo(params object[] args)
    {
         foreach (var arg in args)
             _dict.Add(arg.ToString(), "..");
    }
}

var foo = new Foo("a", "b", "c");
foo.Data.x = 3.14;
Console.Write(foo.Data.a);
```